# Setting up git and ssh and using ssh-agent to store password with msysgit on Windows

Tags: git, ssh, msysgit

Ok, this is a pretty specific question, but I had some challenges figuring it out so I figured I would share my experience so if anyone else runs into the same problems, they can fix it a little faster.

Goal: use ssh-agent and msysgit to -as securely as possible- store ssh key password to prevent having to type it for every git command involving remote repository

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Create a `.bashrc` file in the user directory (default windows `C:\Users\UserName\`)
NOTES: if you think you can just right click in the directory in Windows Explorer and create a file called `.bashrc` you (and me) are sadly mistaken, you'll get an error from Explorer preventing you from creating a file without a name. So, I did this from my git bash by executing `echo 'blah' >> .bashrc` just so I could get the file to edit in notepad to put the required code in it.

2) Edit `.bashrc` in a text editor and put the code found here: https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases#platform-windows under "Auto-launching ssh-agent on msysgit"

3) restart bash.

TROUBLE SHOOTING: `ps` will show all running processes. I found that when I was testing this out, it wasn't prompting me to put in my password when bash was started. When I executed `ps` I noticed many ssh-agents running. After killing them all, I was able to restart git bash and everything worked. Identifying this problem took me the longest.

Comment: I've used the PuTTY family of tools before and they have worked great. However, I've seen some negative feedback in the msysgit forum. People saying it should be removed from the installer as an option. I've researched why there would be that kind of buzz because it seamed to be a great option on a VM that I was using before. Just wanted to post this if someone wanted to use the built in ssh-agent as opposed to the PuTTY toolset

Comment: Good call on killing ssh-agent! I was having trouble until I killed all ssh-agent processes and restarted.

Comment: It's a little late in the game for this, but if you name a file `.bashrc.` in Windows (at least 7+), Windows will give you a `.bashrc` file.

Answer (score -4):

What about to include pass in git repo-url:

```
git clone http://username:password@example.com/git/Project.git .
```

It's not very safe solution, but works :)